# How to know which 'Submit' button was pressed in Node.js

Tags: node.js, forms

When the user connects to my server I would want to display 2 forms, 'Accept' and 'Decline' with post method sent to my server, if the user clicks. How can I know which button was pressed when I handle the request on my server?

Comment: I'm already sending one parameter "id". How can I send a second parameter and how should the code look like on server side? `app.post('/:id:submit',function(req,res){...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send two parameters the REST URL need to be

```
 app.post('buttonclicked/:id/:submit',function(req,res){...}
```

and in the Client end, the post url would be like

```
http://<server domain>/buttonclicked/<id>/<accept/decline>
```