# How to know which button was pressed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, express, body-parser

I'm learning the basics of node.js and express framework.
I have a simple page with two buttons:

```
<form action="/home2" method="post">
    <button name="butt1">butt1</button>
    <button name="butt2">butt2</button>
</form>
```

And i want to see in console which button was pressed:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
    res.render('home2', { title: 'post' });
});
```

In the console i just see

```
undefined
```

How can I access the name of the button?

Comment: What do you think about it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28455284/how-to-know-which-submit-button-was-pressed-in-node-js

Comment: Not shire if I get that. So I can't use two buttons in one form and just read whats written on them?

Comment: 60% of the reason I upvoted this was because you named your buttons "butt1" and "butt2".

Comment: Also  here `console.log(req.body.name)` you have not field with name `name`.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be helpful for you.

```
<form action="/home2" method="post">
   <button name="butt1">butt1</button>
   <button name="butt2">butt2</button>
</form>


router.post('/home2', function(req, res, next) {

  if(req.body.hasOwnProperty("butt1")){
     console.log("butt1 clicked");
  }else{
     console.log("butt2 clicked");
  }
  res.render('home2', { title: 'post' });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all since you are using POST i am assuming you've got the body-parser middleware present, if not check [Body Parser Middleware](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)

your code needs a few changes

in html

```
<form action="/home2" method="post">
    <button name="butt" value='1'>butt1</button>
    <button name="butt" value='2'>butt2</button>
</form>
```

and in express

```
router.post('/home2', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.body.butt);
    res.render('home2', { title: 'post' });
});
```

`req.body.name` needs to be `req.body.butt`

`/` needs to be `/home2`

Answer (score 1):

One trick you can use is to use the two as submit buttons:

```
<form action="/home2" method="post">
    <button name="button_id" value="1" type="submit">butt1</button>
    <button name="button_id" value="2" type="submit">butt2</button>
</form>
```

On server side, you should now get value of `button_id` as 1 or 2, depending on which button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question, but I had the same one and I found a way better solution so I thought I'd share it. You can add different formaction's to different buttons, and do different things with the action in your app. Example:

```
<form action="/home2" method="post">
    <button formaction="wigglebutt" name="butt" value='1'>butt1</button>
    <button formaction="slapbutt" name="butt" value='2'>butt2</button>
</form>
```

And then on the backend:

```
app.post("/wigglebutt", (req, res) => {

});

app.post("/slapbutt", (req, res) => {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="/home2" method="post">
   <input type="submit" name="buttons" value="butt1">
   <input type="submit" name="buttons" value="butt2">
</form>
```

Try this and apply CSS as per your design.

```
app.post("/home2",async(req,res)=>{
 const selected=req.body.buttons;
 console.log(selected);
})
```

Now it works fine with whatever button you click.