# Can I check if a button was pressed in node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I'm trying to check if a button was pressed and then open a new html file, I'm using express.js app.get method to open all of my HTML files. So my question is how can I open a HTML file on the same window when I press a button?

Comment: Welcome @Yahel Myst! Please, add your code so we can see what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

You could but shouldnt. NodeJS is backend.
Also note, that NodeJS is no JavaScript as normally referred to.
It is written/programmed in JavaScript.
To do something on click you would need either a normal `<a>` tag if you just want to open a link or you use **client-side** JavaScript with an `onlick` handler to execute something after a user clicked on an element.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using javascript embedded into the html like this:

```
<button onclick="window.location='http://google.com'">Click me</button>
```

you can also try `window.open=url`

please note that this isn't really using node, just javascript.  this type of behavior belongs in the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think this thread would help you :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33703429/4578393
it uses if statements to check if the button has been pressed

```
 if(req.body.hasOwnProperty("butt1")){
 console.log("butt1 clicked");
```

Taine